# Get Value From Input Field of Table Using Ajax And Update Database By The Data Given

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, datatable

hello I'm trying to update table using ajax but I want only change field qty_kirim on table and update all the qty when button update clicked

when using ajax to send the data I found the response is like the code below

```
{
  "tabel_request": [
    [
      "BRG-2019030003",
      "COOKING STOVE 4 BURNER",
      "YSN-ST4",
      "BRANDON",
      "700",
      "700",
      "900",
      "1",
      "<div class='tengah'><input type='text' onkeypress='isInputNumber(event)' class='tengah qty_terima' style='width:40px!important' oninput='findTotal()' name='qty_terima_1' id='qty_terima_1' value='3' onChange='changeCount(1)'></div>",
      "<a class='btn btn-danger btn-xs Hapus' title='Remove Item'> <i class='fa fa-minus-circle'></i> </a>",
      "3"
    ],
    [
      "BRG-2019030007",
      "UNDERCOUNTER CHILLER 3 SOLID DOOR",
      "ATM-18-3",
      "ATM COOL",
      "1800",
      "700",
      "860",
      "1",
      "<div class='tengah'><input type='text' onkeypress='isInputNumber(event)' class='tengah qty_terima' style='width:40px!important' oninput='findTotal()' name='qty_terima_2' id='qty_terima_2' value='2' onChange='changeCount(2)'></div>",
      "<a class='btn btn-danger btn-xs Hapus' title='Remove Item'> <i class='fa fa-minus-circle'></i> </a>",
      "7"
    ]
  ]
}
```

I need to get value from index 8 to send to database,

but th value is sending html format, like this

```
tabel_request[1][]: <div class='tengah'><input type='text' onkeypress='isInputNumber(event)' class='tengah qty_terima' style='width:40px!important' oninput='findTotal()' name='qty_terima_2' id='qty_terima_2' value='2' onChange='changeCount(2)'></div>
```

.

```
tabel_request[0][]: BRG-2019030003
tabel_request[0][]: COOKING STOVE 4 BURNER
tabel_request[0][]: YSN-ST4
tabel_request[0][]: BRANDON
tabel_request[0][]: 700
tabel_request[0][]: 700
tabel_request[0][]: 900
tabel_request[0][]: 1
tabel_request[0][]: <div class='tengah'><input type='text' onkeypress='isInputNumber(event)' class='tengah qty_terima' style='width:40px!important' oninput='findTotal()' name='qty_terima_1' id='qty_terima_1' value='3' onChange='changeCount(1)'></div>
tabel_request[0][]: <a class='btn btn-danger btn-xs Hapus' title='Remove Item'> <i class='fa fa-minus-circle'></i> </a>
tabel_request[0][]: 3
tabel_request[1][]: BRG-2019030007
tabel_request[1][]: UNDERCOUNTER CHILLER 3 SOLID DOOR
tabel_request[1][]: ATM-18-3
tabel_request[1][]: ATM COOL
tabel_request[1][]: 1800
tabel_request[1][]: 700
tabel_request[1][]: 860
tabel_request[1][]: 1
tabel_request[1][]: <div class='tengah'><input type='text' onkeypress='isInputNumber(event)' class='tengah qty_terima' style='width:40px!important' oninput='findTotal()' name='qty_terima_2' id='qty_terima_2' value='2' onChange='changeCount(2)'></div>
tabel_request[1][]: <a class='btn btn-danger btn-xs Hapus' title='Remove Item'> <i class='fa fa-minus-circle'></i> </a>
tabel_request[1][]: 7
```

of course there will be an error because my data type in datase is integer, and given was string

I need some advice 
1. is that possible when I change the qty it will add value to other hidden cell that I can use as data to stored 
2. or I just directly save to database when I change the value of input field using ajax onchange ?

here is my table code

```
<div id="tblRequestKirimDetails_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper">
<div id="tblRequestKirimDetails_processing" class="dataTables_processing" style="display: none;">Processing...</div>
<table id="tblRequestKirimDetails" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover dataTable" style="width: 100%;" role="grid" aria-describedby="tblRequestKirimDetails_info">
    <thead>
        <tr role="row">
            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 136px;">Kode Barang</th>
            <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 334px;">Nama Barang</th>
            <th class="tengah sorting_disabled text-center" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 77px;">Tipe</th>
            <th class="tengah sorting_disabled text-center" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 90px;">Merk</th>
            <th class="tengah sorting_disabled text-center" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 43px;">W</th>
            <th class="tengah sorting_disabled text-center" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 34px;">D</th>
            <th class="tengah sorting_disabled text-center" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 35px;">H</th>
            <th class="tengah sorting_disabled text-center" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 58px;">Qty PO</th>
            <th class="tengah sorting_disabled text-center" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 54px;">Qty In</th>
            <th width="2px" id="action" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 27px;"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="myBody">
        <tr role="row" class="odd">
            <td>BRG-2019030003</td>
            <td>COOKING STOVE 4 BURNER</td>
            <td class=" text-center">YSN-ST4</td>
            <td class=" text-center">BRANDON</td>
            <td class=" text-center">700</td>
            <td class=" text-center">700</td>
            <td class=" text-center">900</td>
            <td class=" text-center">1</td>
            <td class="text-center qty_diterima" contenteditable="false">
                <div class="tengah">
                    <input type="text" onkeypress="isInputNumber(event)" class="tengah qty_terima" style="width:40px!important" oninput="findTotal()" name="qty_terima_1" id="qty_terima_1" value="3" onchange="changeCount(1)">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs Hapus" title="Remove Item">
                        <i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr role="row" class="even">
                <td>BRG-2019030007</td>
                <td>UNDERCOUNTER CHILLER 3 SOLID DOOR</td>
                <td class=" text-center">ATM-18-3</td>
                <td class=" text-center">ATM COOL</td>
                <td class=" text-center">1800</td>
                <td class=" text-center">700</td>
                <td class=" text-center">860</td>
                <td class=" text-center">1</td>
                <td class="text-center qty_diterima" contenteditable="false">
                    <div class="tengah">
                        <input type="text" onkeypress="isInputNumber(event)" class="tengah qty_terima" style="width:40px!important" oninput="findTotal()" name="qty_terima_2" id="qty_terima_2" value="2" onchange="changeCount(2)">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs Hapus" title="Remove Item">
                            <i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot style="border: 0px 0px 0px 0px solid #ecf0f5!important;">
                <tr style="font-size: 15px;font-weight: 600; background-color: #ecf0f5!important ">
                    <td colspan="7" style="border: 0px 0px 0px 0px solid #ecf0f5!important; padding: 8px 10px 8px 10px;" class="text-center" rowspan="1">
                        <span style="float:right;">Total Req | Terima</span>
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="1" style="border: 0px 0px 0px 0px solid #ecf0f5!important; padding: 8px 10px 8px 10px;" id="totalItems" class="text-center" rowspan="1">
                        <div class="tengah">
                            <span class="tengah" id="totalItem">2</span>
                            <input type="hidden" class="form-control kanan" id="total_item" name="total_item" value="0">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="1" style="border: 0px 0px 0px 0px solid #ecf0f5!important; padding: 8px 10px 8px 10px" id="total_terima" class="text-center" rowspan="1">2</td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
            <div class="dataTables_info" id="tblRequestKirimDetails_info" role="status" aria-live="polite">Showing 1 to 2 of 2 entries</div>
        </div>
```

and below is my ajax

```
$(document).on('submit', function(e)
    {
        if(!e.isDefaultPrevented())
        {
            var table = $("#tblRequestKirimDetails").DataTable();
            var jumlah = table.rows().count();

            if ( jumlah == 0 ) {
                swal({
                    title: "Tidak Ada Data",
                    text: "Pastikan Barang Yang Akan dikirim tidak kosong",
                    type: "warning"
                });
            }
            else
            {   
                var _data = {
                    //this code is need to be valid before Ajax script executed
                    kode_keluar: $('input[name=kode_keluar]').val(),

                    tabel_request: table.rows().data().toArray(),
                    qty_kirim : table.row().$('.qty_dikirim').serializeObject()
                };

                console.log(_data);

                $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    }
                });


                    $.ajax({
                        url : "{{ route('admin.barang_keluar.update', [$bm->id]) }}",
                        method: "PUT",
                        type: "PUT",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: _data,
                        success: function(data)
                        {
                            console.log(data);
                            $('.save').addClass('disabled');  
                            swal({
                                type: 'success',
                                title: "Success",
                                text: "Data Barang Masuk Sudah Simpan",
                                type: "success",
                                // timer: 2000,
                            }).then(function()
                            {
                                // window.location = "{{ route('admin.barang_masuk.index') }}";
                            });
                        },
                        error: function (xhr) {
                            swal({
                                type: 'error',
                                title: 'Oops...',
                                text: 'Something went wrong!'
                            });
                        }

                    });

            }
        }
        return false;
    });
```